# OpenJDK or Sun JDK for SCTP implementation

Tags: java, sctp

I'm setting up an Ubuntu VM for my project that requires SCTP connections. I'm confused as which Java7 to install for this - OpenJDK7 or SunJDK 7?

Which one would have the most support? I'll be prowling on the internet to find SCTP API's and usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, it probably makes no difference which one you use.  OpenJDK and the Oracle (not Sun!) badged JDK are based on the common OpenJDK code base.  The biggest difference in practice (IMO) is that patches seem to arrive earlier for the Oracle branded version  than for the OpenJDK-based packages in typical Linux distros.

> Which one would have the most support?

I you want support for Java, contact Oracle sales and they can arrange a support contract.  As part of that, they will advise you on which they can provide better support for.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. By support I meant internet support/developer community support.

Comment: @user2441441 - I wouldn't think there would be any difference.  Have you looked to see how much *"internet support/developer community support"* there actually is?  I'd have that was more important ... if you think you are going to need support.